# MySQL Workbench missing closing parenthesis

Tags: mysql, sql, database, web, workbench

This code was generated in Workbench after creating model for synchronizing with server. But after my trying synchronize this model, Workbench say: operation has completed with errors.
I put this code into "query window" Workbench and see highlighted syntax error on line **PRIMARY KEY (`idGroup`)  COMMENT ''**.
Why this code incorrect? Thanks!

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `everest_journal_db`.`Groups` (
  `idGroup` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `titleGroup` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idGroup`)  COMMENT ''
  )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `everest_journal_db`.`table_from_workbench` ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `everest_journal_db`.`simple_table` ;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: The code basically works in SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa47b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we know it, it's a bug. To temporary workaround just remove all occurence of COMMENT ''. Feel free to leave a comment under this [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77910). We're working on it to fix it, so stay tuned for upcoming release.